# String field value length in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, field, string-length

The data type of the field is String. I would like to fetch the data where character length of field name is greater than 40.

I tried these queries but returning error.
1.

```
db.usercollection.find(
{$where: "(this.name.length > 40)"}
).limit(2);

output :error: {
    "$err" : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined near '40)' ",
    "code" : 16722
}
```

this is working in 2.4.9 But my version is 2.6.5

Comment: Did you try gt instead of >

Answer (score 237, accepted):

**For MongoDB 3.6 and newer:**

The [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language, thus you can leverage the use of [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/#exp._S_strLenCP) operator to check the length of the string as follows:

```
db.usercollection.find({ 
    name: { $exists: true },
    $expr: { $gt: [{ $strLenCP: '$name' }, 40] } 
})
```

---

**For MongoDB 3.4 and newer:**

You can also use the aggregation framework with the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) pipeline operator that allows you to proccess the logical condition with the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator and uses the special operations [`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or [`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match), except that [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

As for the logical condition, there are [String Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-string/) that you can use [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/#exp._S_strLenCP) operator to check the length of the string. If the length is [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/#exp._S_gt) a specified value, then this is a true match and the document is "kept". Otherwise it is "pruned" and discarded.

---

Consider running the following aggregate operation which demonstrates the above concept:

```
db.usercollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { name: { $exists: true } } },
    { $redact: {
         $cond: [
            { $gt: [ { $strLenCP: "$name" }, 40] },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    } },
    { $limit: 2 }
])
```

---

If using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where), try your query without the enclosing brackets:

```
db.usercollection.find({ $where: "this.name.length > 40" }).limit(2);
```

A better query would be to to check for the field's existence and then check the length:

```
db.usercollection.find({ name: { $type: 2 }, $where: "this.name.length > 40" }).limit(2);
```

or:

```
db.usercollection.find({ name: { $exists: true }, $where: "this.name.length > 
40" }).limit(2);
```

MongoDB evaluates non-[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) query operations before [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) expressions and non-`$where` query statements may use an index. A much better performance is to store the length of the string as another field and then you can index or search on it; applying [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) will be much slower compared to that. It's recommended to use JavaScript expressions and the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator as a last resort when you can't structure the data in any other way, or when you are dealing with a
small subset of data.

---

A different and faster approach that avoids the use of the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator is the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator. Consider the following pattern which searches for

```
db.usercollection.find({"name": {"$type": 2, "$regex": /^.{41,}$/}}).limit(2);
```

**Note** - From the **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)**:

> If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular
> expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a
> collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular
> expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential
> matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a
> “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the
> index that fall within that range.
>
> A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a
> caret `(^)` or a left anchor `(\A)`, followed by a string of simple
> symbols. For example, the regex `/^abc.*/` will be optimized by
> matching only against the values from the index that start with `abc`.
>
> Additionally, while `/^a/, /^a.*/,` and `/^a.*$/` match equivalent
> strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these
> expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however,
> `/^a.*/`, and `/^a.*$/` are slower. `/^a/` can stop scanning after
> matching the prefix.

Comment: All the 3 queries working fine. But the first one is accepting upto 15. ie "this.name.length > 15". If we give 16 or above it is giving the same error.

Comment: If we want to execute the same for inner document like profile.name then can you please suggest a syntax for it.

Comment: For an embedded document field try `db.usercollection.find({"profile.name": {$type: 2}, $where: "this.profile.name.length > 40"}).limit(2); `

Comment: working perfect but i was wondering, is there any other way also of doing this. like Mongo Way `db.collection.find({'country.length':{$gt:20}})` something like it.

Comment: @chridam's answer is perfect! But just wanted to emphasize the fact that the error is more to do with checking the existence of the field in the record rather than the presence / absence of brackets. Even with / without the brackets it did not work for me.

As such,

`db.usercollection.find({name: {$exists: true}, $where: "this.name.length > 40"}).limit(2);`

is the right query and will always work.

Comment: My requirement is to get the length of the string field in the result. As we don't have support for "strLenCP" in 3.0/prior versions, how can we achieve that?

Comment: @sureshgoud Would suggest you create a new question for this as comments are more likely to be purged in the long-run

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040884/alternate-to-strlencp-field-in-mongodb-3-0prior-versions

Answer (score 28):

Queries with `$where` and `$expr` are slow if there are too many documents.

Using `$regex` is much faster than `$where`, `$expr`.

```js
db.usercollection.find({ 
  "name": /^[\s\S]{40,}$/, // name.length >= 40
})

or 

db.usercollection.find({ 
  "name": { "$regex": "^[\s\S]{40,}$" }, // name.length >= 40
})
```

This query is the same meaning with

```
db.usercollection.find({ 
  "$where": "this.name && this.name.length >= 40",
})

or

db.usercollection.find({ 
    "name": { "$exists": true },
    "$expr": { "$gte": [ { "$strLenCP": "$name" }, 40 ] } 
})
```

I tested each queries for my collection.

```
# find
$where: 10529.359ms
$expr: 5305.801ms
$regex: 2516.124ms

# count
$where: 10872.006ms
$expr: 2630.155ms
$regex: 158.066ms
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is one of the way in mongodb you can achieve this.

```
db.usercollection.find({ $where: 'this.name.length < 4' })
```

Comment: as this query uses javascript expression, this can't use the mongodb indexes, so it's slow.

Comment: `$where` may also not be allowed on free MongoDB SaaS tiers (e.g. it isn't on the Atlas 512MB plan).

Comment: That's right. As far as I know, Even AWS Document DB also doesn't support it as of now.

Answer (score 9):

Find anything with a `name` with 40 or more characters:

```
db.usercollection.find({name: /.{40}/})
```

(simplified the RegEx from [Fumiya Karasawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5760756/fumiya-karasawa)'s answer)

Answer (score 7):

This query will give both field value and length:

```
db.usercollection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        "name": 1,
        "length": { $strLenCP: "$name" }
    }} ])
```

Comment: and if one doesnt want to use aggregate then it can be 
`db.collection.find({$expr: {$lt: [{$strLenCP: "$name"}, 20]}})`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar kind of scenario, but in my case string is not a 1st level attribute. It is inside an object. In here I couldn't find a suitable answer for it. So I thought to share my solution with you all(Hope this will help anyone with a similar kind of problem).

```
Parent Collection 

{
"Child":
{
"name":"Random Name",
"Age:"09"
}
}
```

Ex: If we need to get only collections that having child's name's length is higher than 10 characters.

```
 db.getCollection('Parent').find({$where: function() { 
for (var field in this.Child.name) { 
    if (this.Child.name.length > 10) 
        return true;

}
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution:

[image: Sample Data from MongoDB]

Here word is field which contains a string of various length.

```
const result = await client
    .db("colors")
    .collection("words")
    .aggregate([
      {
        $addFields: {
          length: { $strLenCP: "$word" },
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          length: { $gt: 5 },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          word: "$word",
          length: "$length",
        },
      }, 
    ]);
```