# Check through mongodb colletion for values in a field too large to index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a mongodb collection with a field that I'm trying to index. It's a string field titled 'title'. There's about 9 million different entries and I'm just trying to get rid of the junk ones.

When I tried indexing it with:

```
db.getCollection("review_metadata").createIndex({"title" : 1})
```

I get this error:

> db.getCollection("review_metadata").createIndex({"title" : 1})

```
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing amazon_reviews.review_metadata.$title_1 1860 { : \"***Super Charger*** Ultra Slim 40W AC Power Adapter Cord for Samsung Notebook/UltraBook : NP300U1A, NP300U1A-A01US, NP305U1A, NP305U1A-A01US, NP305U1A...\" }",
        "code" : 17282
}
```

So, is there a way to search through all of the values in the title field for values that would be too large to index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577713/string-field-value-length-in-mongodb

Comment: Agreed, just use a minimum length of 1012 to find the offending docs. `db.test.find({title: /^.{1012,}$/})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [manaul](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) there is 1024 bytes limit in indexed field.
As you are going to index text field  - [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) could be a good solution

```
db.review_metadata.createIndex(
   {
     title: "text",
     otherFieldThatCouldBeIndexedToo: "text"
   }
 )
```

Comment: I went with this solution as I'm just testing something out and need to do easy /^**** search through the data. Thanks.