# Length function filter - mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm beginner in Mongodb with c#. I use Mongodb Driver C#
I want to create a filter with condition is lenght of string=n.
I check the function support it but i'm not found.

I have research and i use code below

var filterBuilder = Builders.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq("this.MyString.length ", lenght);

but it's not working. I need your helps. 
Thanks all

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577713/string-field-value-length-in-mongodb

Comment: Is `lenght` a typo of `length`? Check the second argument being passed here: filterBuilder.Eq("this.MyString.length ", **lenght**);

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to return all documents where a certain field of type string has a particular length? What does your data look like? What is your desired output?