# Mongo C# driver - Length support?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/expressions/) says I can use :

```
Find(x => x.FavoriteNumbers.Length == 3);
```

If I write:

```
await col.Find(f=>f.AuthType > 2).ToListAsync()
```

I do get the expected result because all `AuthType` are greater than `2`.

[image]

But now, let's say that I want to filter all records with `Id.Length>2`:

```
await col.Find(f=>f.Id.Length>2).ToListAsync();
```

This returns 0 records.

**Question:**

How can I get all the records with Id's Length >2 ?

I've already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332215/length-function-filter-mongodb-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1) , but with no answer and the dup is not in c#

Comment: I don't know mongo, just cardboard analysing: Is ID a string, byte array etc, or something else that actually has a .Length property? What if it's a Guid or something that doesn't have a Length? How to format it to a string so you can tell how long it is?

Comment: @CaiusJard It's `Id.ToString().Length` . Id here is a string. not a guid. this is not how guid looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can write below line of code and try to inspect it by hovering:

```
var query = await col.Find(f=>f.Str.Length>2)
```

What happens is that MongoDB will transalte it into regular expression like `{find({ "Str" : /^.{3,}$/s })}` and this regex gets executed on the database side. Nothing unexpected. The problem occurs when you change `Str` into `Id` which gets translated into:

```
{find({ "_id" : /^.{3,}$/s })}
```

and you get no result as your field's name is still `Id`. The reason why it's happening is described [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/bson/mapping/#the-id-member). So MongoDB driver by convention infers that field named `Id`should be translated into `_id`. To fix that you can explicitly specify on your data model which field should be considered as `_id` using `BsonId` attribute:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId RealId { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

To apply type conversion (int -> string) you have to rely on [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) operator introduced in MongoDB. The idea is simple: you add new field using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and then run [$strLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/index.html) on it to verify string length. Unfortunately there's no easy way to do it in C# using strongly typed way so you can use `BsonDocument` class which lets you use strings as Aggregation Pipeline definition:

```
var q = Col.Aggregate()
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ $addFields: { AuthTypeInt: { $toString: \"$AuthType\" } } }"))
            .Match(BsonDocument.Parse("{ $expr: { $gt: [ { \"$strLenCP\": \"$AuthTypeInt\" }, 2 ] } }"));

var data = await q.ToListAsync();
```

The code looks ugly but it should be a way faster than running plain JavaScript (more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html#op._S_where))

Comment: `await col.Find(f=>f.AuthType.ToString().Length==3).ToListAsync()` failes on `{document}{authType}.ToString().Length is not supported`

Comment: @RoyiNamir don't use `ToString()` there's no way to translate that operator into something on database side. Or there is a way but it's not implemented in the driver yet. Just run it on a field that's already defined as string both on DB and in C# class

Comment: @RoyiNamir two different things: for strings it works as the documentation says with the caveat for conventions (field named `Id`). For ints it won't because you're trying to convert types (using `.ToString()`) which is not implemented in C# driver (was introduced in MongoDB 4.0). Can't you just check `AuthType > 99` ?

Comment: First of all , thank you for your help. I'm learning mongo , and I wanted to know by a simple tests how can I achieve `this.authType.toString().length>2` - in a C# way. Sure I can check its value. But tomorrow i'd want to filter by its length. Hence my question. How can I do `this.authType.toString().length>2` in C#  way ? BTW i've posted an answer but I don't like JS in C#.

Comment: @RoyiNamir there is a way to do that in MongoDB 4.0 or newer but the code won't be so nice as you expect. Is that fine for you (MongoDB version) ?

Comment: Sure.  I'd be happy to see the code  I have the latest version I think. I've installed it yesterday from the official site - locally)

Comment: btw - I've created `RealId` - but it doesn't have `Length` https://i.imgur.com/8231VWX.jpg

Comment: Modified my answer. Answering your question: `Length` is available on `strings`, `RealId` was supposed to be an `ObjectId` and represent `_id` field which has to occur in your data anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196413/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-mickl).

Comment: Can u plz have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503195/cannot-use-mongos-filter-with-datetime-and-bsonstring ?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it in a very ugly way, involving JS:

```
var ll=new BsonDocument("$where", new BsonJavaScript("function() { return this.authType.toString().length>2; }"));

var t2 = await col.Find(ll).ToListAsync();
```

[image]

What is the C# equivalent solution?