# How to check if string length is >0 in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am firing mgo from GoLang on MongoDb to find records which have trimmed string length greater than zero, I tried below but neither is working, please help.

```
findQuery["shopname"] = bson.M{"$where": "len > 0"}
findQuery["shopname"] = bson.M{"$where": "shopname.len > 0"}
findQuery["shopname"] = bson.M{"$where": "this.shopname.len > 0"}
findQuery["shopname"] = bson.M{"$regex": ".*.*"}
```

Comment: Please help, unable to find how to resolve this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String field value length in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577713/string-field-value-length-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking just for non-empty values, try this:

```
bson.M{"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are best!

Answer (score 0):

Another way or another approach would be to check if 0th element of array exists or not.

```
"arr.0" : bson.M{"$exists": true}
```