# Alternate to $strLenCP field in mongoDB 3.0[prior versions]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently using mongo 3.0v. I've got a requirement to find the length of each string in the result from the aggregate command.

For example:

```
db.getCollection('temp').find()
[
 {"key": "value1"},
 {"key": "value2" },
 {"key": "valuee2"}
]
```

This query gives the length of the key field:

```
db.getCollection('temp').aggregate([{
 $project: {
  "strLength": {"$strLenCP": "$key"}
 }
}])
```

Like:
[
{"strLength": 6},
{"strLength": 6},
{"strLength": 7}
]

But `$strLenCP` key is not supported in prior 3.4 versions. So are there any alternate options for this?