# MongoDB string field value length in Yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-active-records

I just read [How to query the string field value length in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577713/string-field-value-length-in-mongodb) and successfully got a query working when used directly in MongoDB console. The query I used was:

```
db.getCollection('language').find({
  name: {$ne: ''}, 
  $where: "this.i18n.length < 3"
})
```

I am now trying to duplicate the same in Yii2:

```
$languages = Language::find()
  ->where(['$ne', 'name', ''])
  ->andWhere(['<', 'this.i18n.length', '3'])
  ->all();
```

but the array is empty.

I have tried the query without string length:

```
$languages = Language::find()
  ->where(['$ne', 'name', ''])
  ->all();
```

and the array is populated.

I have also tried the query with string length alone:

```
$languages1 = Language::find()
  ->where(['<', 'this.i18n.length', '3'])
  ->all();
$languages2 = Language::find()
  ->where(['<', 'i18n.length', '3'])
  ->all();
```

but array remains empty.

Question is: How do I get `$where: "this.i18n.length < 3"` to work in Yii2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there's no way to query the db directly. I have instead filtered the results in php:

```
$languages = Language::find()->where(['$ne', 'name', ''])->all();
foreach ($languages as $fac) {
  if(strlen($fac->i18n)<3){
    // my code here
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test right now, but try something like this :

```
$languages = Language::find()
  ->where(['$ne', 'name', ''])
  ->andWhere(['=', '$where','this.i18n.length<3'])
  ->all();
```