# mongodb how to find a length of string in a array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hi i have a little problem, i hope someone know that how can i deal with this problem.

```
  {
    "isim": "This is topic - 2",
    "resim": "anywhere2.png",
    "ozellik": {
      "detay": ["qv", "asv", "asd" , "vx"],
      "bilgi": ["xc", "bv", "hjm" , "sax"]
    }
  },

  {
    "isim": "This is topic - 1",
    "resim": "anywhere.png",
    "ozellik": {
      "detay": ["sa", "as", "de", "ed"],
      "bilgi": ["bv", "cv", "asd", "dsa"]
    }
  }
```

this is my db, I can do that:
bilgi[2] like this

```
{ $project: {
        _id: 0,
        isim: 1,
        boyut: { $arrayElemAt: ["$ozellik.bilgi", -2] },
      }}
```

and this code return following lines:

```
{
    "isim": "This is topic - 2",
    "boyut": "hjm"
  },

  {
    "isim": "This is topic - 1",
    "boyut": "asd"
  }
```

here is, i want to know what is length of "hjm" or "asd"

this is not work for me : [String field value length in array in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580988/string-field-value-length-in-array-in-mongodb)

and i try this :

```
boyut: { $strLenCP : {$arrayElemAt: ["$ozellik.bilgi", -2]} },
```

and node js is say that, [Screenshot](https://i.hizliresim.com/trfnqg.png)

```
MongoError: $strLenCP requires a string argument, found: missing
```

Comment: what is wrong from that code  ? https://i.hizliresim.com/trfnqg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening when it search for `$arrayElemAt` position -2, if array element size is less than or equal to 1 then, this function will return `null`, and `$strLenCP` operator supports only string type,

You can use `$ifNull` to prevent this error,

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      isim: 1,
      boyut: {
        $strLenCP: {
          $ifNull: [
            { $arrayElemAt: ["$ozellik.bilgi", -2] },
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u1QEQ3wJhKH)